# Checkbox To Do list update SQLite database Xamarin / .net Maui

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, model, maui

I am trying to make a checkbox work with SQLite when checking it done it will update the Done property in the model for tasks. The checkbox is in a collectionview with itemsource set to a list of tasks. Using sqlite-net-pcl

XAML Element:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox_Done" IsChecked="{Binding Done}" CheckedChanged="CheckedDone"  />
```

C# code behind:

```
private async void CheckedDone(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var temp = sender as Tasks;
        temp.Done = !temp.Done;
        await App.Database.UpdateTask(temp);
    }
```

My database update function

```
public Task<int> UpdateTask(Tasks task)
    {
        return db.UpdateAsync(task);
    }
```

The sender as tasks does not appear to be working, what am I doing wrong here>?

Comment: `sender` is the control that raised the event - in your case, the `CheckBox`.  You are also (I think) working against yourself by both binding `Checked` **and** modifying it in the event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sender` is the **control** that rasied the event

```
private async void CheckedDone(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // get the sender
    var cb = sender as CheckBox;

    // use the BindingContext to get the bound Task
    var task = cb.BindingContext as Tasks;

    // task should already reflect the updated Value, no need
    // to change it again
    await App.Database.UpdateTask(task);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. I appreciate the help!